# Unable to build .Net core 1.1 project with vs 2017 and .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-2.0

I am fairly new to the .net world and not sure what I did wrong.

I am trying to build existing .net core project with core 2.0 .

Steps that i performed

1. Upgraded/Downloaded .net core sdk 2.0
2. downloaded vs2017 v15.2
3. tried to open repository with vs2017 ( which opens with erros like "Predefined type int32 is not defined or imported" , for every datatype)
4. build the project , this fails with errors as below

   [image]
5. tried multiple things like :

   - uninstall nugget package and reinstall
   - Uninstall all .net core version apart from 2.0
   - cleared nugget package catche
   - closing reopening vs multiple times
   - tried to create new project ( which works fine )

Can someone help , 1 more thing is with same repository and SDK and VS2017 it works fine on other system ( has to be issue with my local system ).

Answer (score 0):

**Identified the issue and below is the solution.**

I had two version of VS 2017 installed on my system.
I did upgrade the version of my VS , but instead of replacing existing one , it installed a parallel new version. After uninstalling and intalling only latest version , problem was fixed.